# Issues when computing convex hull of large dataset using qhull/SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, convex-hull, qhull

I started to experiment using the `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` function, that (if I understood correctly) is a wrapper for the `qhull` C library. I am using SciPy 0.19.1 with Python3.

I first worked with a real-world dataset that features 700 points in 21 dimensions, and `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` crashes, with this error: `scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6235 qhull error (qh_memalloc): negative request size (-2003053336).  Did int overflow due to high-D?`.

After a few attempts using the following sample Python3 code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(40,21)
print("Computing convex hull of X (shape: " + str(X.shape) + ")...")
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
hull = ConvexHull(X)
```

I managed to narrow the issue down to dimensionality. With 39 randomly generated points in 21 dimensions, it works. With 40 points, sometimes it crashes, sometimes it succeeds. I am not sure, but it seems there's a memory allocation error?

1. Is there a way to avoid the memory problem? Are 700 points too many for convex hull algorithms?
2. Skimming through search results in Google, I noticed that there are some algorithms to compute an approximation of a convex hull. Do you recommend them? Could they work in my situation? Is there already a Python implementation for some of them?
3. Potentially I would like to compute convex hulls of high-dimensional spaces, up to 100,000 dimensions. Is this madness, or can it be done in a sensible way?

Comment: Maybe you could approximate the large dimension space with a smaller set of linear combinations? https://github.com/paulcon/active_subspaces/blob/master/tutorials/basic.ipynb

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I think your edit is problematic. When reading *I noticed that there are some algorithms to compute an approximation of a convex hull. Do you recommend them? Could they work in my situation?* obviously made me think: isnt' that broad, but more important: the author did not mention anything about his use-case. This information was removed with your edit.

Comment: I've encountered this exact same issue while using `scipy.optimize.shgo` in a 12 dimensional parameter space. I'm wondering if some sort of a solution has been established since. Perhaps I could locally edit scipy's source code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: ConvexHull with struggle in high dimensions

ConvexHull uses qhull. I've played with an equivalent implementation in matlab (also used qhull) with a problem in high dimensions owing to the large amount of memory required. I contacted the developers who confirmed this to be an issue.

For help in monitoring Qhull's memory performance see 'Performance of Qhull"
http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-code.htm#performance

"When to use Qhull" may also be of help
http://www.qhull.org/html/index.htm#when